# visual basic 6.0 project menu corrupted

Tags: ide, vb6

I do not know why the project menu in visual basic 6.0 IDE has been corrupted and I don't see
all menu items such as references, project properties,....

it might be useful to know that I have installed SP6.0 of visual studio 2000 enterprise edition.

any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vb6 ide can be customized.
Try right clicking on a menu or toolbar and select "Customize...", you should be able to see a full list of commands (I can't recall, but there should be an option to reset it, too).